# Love2D Renderer Error

Tags: debugging, lua, render, love2d

I am following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFE94uJodVs&list=PL5gRzHmN4Dg0Q9J9mMQwzVSbRnj2zWcUH&index=2) that is teaching me about how to make a platformer. In the second tutorial, we started to make a renderer. Whenever I run the code and test the renderer, I get this error

```
    Error: main.lua:24: attempt to index global 'renderer' (a nil value)
```

I have *no* idea how to fix it, so here is my code.

renderer.lua

```
    local Renderer = {}
    local num_of_layers = 5
    local insert = table.insert
    local remove = table.remove

    function Renderer:create()

      local renderer = {}
      --
      renderer.drawers = {}
      for i = 0,num_of_layers do
        renderer.drawers[i] = {}
      end
      --
      function renderer:addRenderer(obj, Layer)
        local l = layer or 0
        insert(self.drawers[l], obj)
      end
      --
      function renderer:draw()
        for layer = 0,#self.drawers do
          for draw = 0,#self.drawers[layer] do

            local obj = self.drawers[layer][draw]
            if obj ~= nil then
              obj:draw()
            end
          end
          end
        end
      return renderer
    end
    --
    return Renderer
```

Here is main.lua

```
    local Renderer = require("libs/renderer")

    Renderer = Renderer:create()

    function love.load()

      love.graphics.setBackgroundColor(255, 255, 255)

      --Loading Classes
      player_load()
      --Loading Classes

    end
    --
    function love.update(dt)



    end
    --
    function love.draw()

      renderer:draw()

    end
```

Thanks to everyone who is reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua is case sensitive.

Renderer = Renderer:create() is not the same as
renderer = Renderer:create()

Comment: OMG! I cant believe I didn't notice that! Thanks so much!